# Best way to play a chord with NAudio

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

I was wondering what's the best way to play a chord in NAudio and C#.
Is it possible to send multiple notes in one message?
Or just write a for(each) loop and send a MIDI message on and of for each note?
I had some timing issues with the last one and big chords on slower machines.

Comment: How exactly are you sending the notes? Show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just send MIDI note on events one after the other for each note. Then when you're done, send MIDI note off events. There is a Windows API that lets you send batches of MIDI events in one go which may perform slightly better, but NAudio doesn't have a wrapper for it.